# Python's email sending slow only on certain net connections - getfqdn takes 30 seconds

Tags: python, networking, dns

I am experiencing a problem on my dev machine (MacBook Air with MacOS 10.8.3) with sending email. It is painfully slow. However, the slowness is dependent on how I connect to the internet. If I am on my home WiFi connection, the email sending takes ~30 seconds. If I am connecting in some other way, like at a friend's house or via LTE through my iPad, the email sending is quick (< 1 second).

Using Django debug_toolbar I have identified the `getfqdn` function as the culprit. It is called when opening the connection to the SMTP server:

```
Call    CumTime Per TotTime Per Count
... SNIP ...
31.673  31.673  0.000   0.000   1
- /Users/<SNIP>/virtualenv/src/django/django/core/mail/message.py in send(249)
31.627  31.627  0.000   0.000   1
- /Users/<SNIP>/virtualenv/src/django/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py in send_messages(80)
31.623  31.623  0.000   0.000   1
- /Users/<SNIP>/virtualenv/src/django/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py in open(37)
30.821  30.821  0.000   0.000   1
- /Users/<SNIP>/virtualenv/src/django/django/core/mail/utils.py in get_fqdn(14)
30.147  30.147  0.000   0.000   1
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py in getfqdn(124)
30.147  30.147  0.000   0.000   1
```

I have tried using the fully qualified domain name `smtp.sendgrid.net` or the IP address `50.97.69.146` as the `EMAIL_HOST`. Both scenarios consistently result in `getfqdn` taking ~30 seconds.

Seeing if perhaps the problem is not lower down, I have tried telneting to the SMTP port using the terminal. When I telnet from the terminal, it takes about 5 seconds if I use the host name:

```
> time echo 'quit' | telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587 
Trying 75.126.83.211...
Connected to smtp.sendgrid.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
echo 'quit'  0.00s user 0.00s system 45% cpu 0.002 total
telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587  0.02s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 5.197 total
```

or about 250ms if I use the IP address:

```
> time echo 'quit' | telnet 50.97.69.146 587      
Trying 50.97.69.146...
Connected to 50.97.69.146-static.reverse.softlayer.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
echo 'quit'  0.00s user 0.00s system 42% cpu 0.002 total
telnet 50.97.69.146 587  0.02s user 0.01s system 8% cpu 0.259 total
```

I understand that part of the problem (demonstrated by the terminal experiment) is caused by a slow DNS lookup (~5 seconds). Where does the rest of the slowdown come from in Django/Python?

Comment: One possibility is that the mail server you're using is imposing a delay if you're not on an IP subnet it knows about. I have this set up on my mail server as an anti-spam measure.

Comment: That would be possible and I have thought about it, since I am based in Poland. However, I have seen it be quick consistently with every other uplink except my cable modem. It looks like the DNS server is at the heart of the issue (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to using Google's public DNS servers (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) and all these issues went away. Somehow the DNS server was at the heart of this issue.

I would still be interested in knowing why Python's call takes 30 seconds to resolve the domain name, when the DNS resolution is done in the terminal it takes 5 seconds.

Comment: wireshark would probably reveal something interesting.  Are different names being resolved by Python and your telnet command?  Likely so, and by seeing the differences in wireshark you'll probably get a pretty good idea of the cause of the problem.